# Angular localhost on iphone

Tags: angular, localhost

I'm trying to access my localhost on my iphone to test my angular app but I can't get it to work. Anyone else figure this out?

I'm on a mac and my npm script looks like this

```
"start": "ng serve -e=local --host 0.0.0.0 --public --port 8000 --ssl",
```

and I'm trying to hit `http://mymac.local:8000` on my phone, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. The workaround is to use the --prod flag while serving your angular application.
Ex: `ng serve --prod --host<Your IP>`
P.S: This obviously takes more time(due to prod) to build and more time to reflect changes while debugging

Comment: It didn't work for me (for crazy error), but anyway, thank you for the great idea. In my  case I've ended up for making a build `ng build`, and then accessed it with any web server (e.g. Apache) like localhost/myproject/dist (on iPhone, accordingly, it was similar to http://192.168.0.102/myproject/dist)